# phpUnit/ZF1 -- halt execution of code after redirect

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I am writing tests for a ZF1 application, here is the init of my controller:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');

    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if(!in_array($action,array('login','logout'))) {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            // Identity exists; get it
            $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
        } else {
            $this->_redirector->gotoUrl('/hr/index/login?redirect='.urlencode($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri()));
        }
    }
    $this->_user = AdminUserQuery::create()->findOneByUsername($identity);
    $this->view->user = $this->_user;
    ...
}
```

and the test in question:

```
public function testNoAuthGivesLogin() {
    $this->dispatch('/hr');
    $this->assertRedirectTo( '/hr/index/login?redirect=%2Fhr' );
}
```

Simple... basically if there is no auth, redirect to the login. this works in the browser, but in phpUnit it continues to execute the code after the redirect, meaning that the properties that get set below it are not there, specifically $this->_user, so in my index action, when it calls getId() on $this->_user, it throws an error

How do I tell phpUnit to stop executing code after a redirect is detected, if I add a die() or exit() or even $this->_redirector->setExit(true); it halts the phpUnit session entirely and no tests get run.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find the code execution continues in the browser as well, you just aren't seeing the errors. I believe there's a `gotoUrlAndExit()` which you want to use instead.

Comment: nope, it still throws the exit and kills the phpUnit Session